# How to simulate hardware media control buttons on an Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, media, playback, android-hardware

Android supports hardware play / pause buttons on headsets and attached devices.  I am trying to find a way to test support for those devices on an emulator.  The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html#PlaybackControls) talks about how to add support for hardware playback controls, but, unfortunately, I can't find documentation of how to emulate them.  Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can send keyevents using adb

```
   adb shell input keyevent <keycode>
```

keycode for play - 126, pause - 85 (see [KeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html))

Comment: Note that 85 can also be "Play/Pause". That's the one I use all of the time so I don't have to track whether the media is playing or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do this, from an Android application. You can call [`AudioManager.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(KeyEvent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#dispatchMediaKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent)) and pass in the events with the necessary key code. Don't forget to call it twice, first with the event with `ACTION_DOWN`, then with `ACTION_UP`.