# How to check google assistant Playback controls in TV emulator via command line?

Tags: android, command-line, google-search, android-tv, google-assistant-sdk

I am currently working on google assistant implementation with our existing media player application, I am able to perform search action by following command line on Android emulator,

```
adb shell am start -a "android.search.action.GLOBAL_SEARCH" --es query \"SEARCH STRING\"
```

Ref link: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/video-playback-with-google-assistant-on.html

But, I want to check playback controls in Android TV emulator via command-line, and I am not sure how to make it. Reference image,

[image]

Comment: Try to check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034050/how-to-simulate-hardware-media-control-buttons-on-an-android-emulator) if it helps. Also, if you are going to check the documentation about [`KeyEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent), all key and button events was listed there and I think that would suffice if you are looking for this list.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 Thanks for sharing details, but I need help to send adb voice command to TV emulator.