# Back button not working on android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-sdk-2.3

I try to start an android sdk emulator, but when I press the back button this error appears:

```
INFO    | Critical: Failed to load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/mapsjs/gen_204?csp_test=true: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'qrc://' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'qrc://' is therefore not allowed access. (qrc:/html/js/common.js:0, (null))

INFO    | Critical: Failed to load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/mapsjs/gen_204?csp_test=true: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'qrc://' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'qrc://' is therefore not allowed access. (qrc:/html/js/common.js:0, (null))
```

I use Ubuntu and try to start the emulator through terminal, I use the avdmanager of the google cmdline-tools (latest version) and this is the AVD that I try to use:

```
    Name: my_avd_29ii
    Path: /home/user/.android/avd/my_avd_29ii.avd
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
          Based on: Android 10.0 (Q) Tag/ABI: google_apis/x86
  Sdcard: 512 MB
```

Comment: I'm currently working on it, I can tell you right away thought that this error is unrelated, just use the flag `-no-location-ui` and it won't show. If you really need the back button you can also use `adb shell input KEYCODE_BACK` works for me, but that's super annoying, it would be this that the control just work, I'll keep diggin, but please post the answer if you find it, it's making me mad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking around I found that there were two ways to push hardware events to the emulator:

#### [First method](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-console)

This method uses `telnet`, like so:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 5554
auth <auth-key>
event send EV_KEY:KEY_BACK:0
event send EV_KEY:KEY_BACK:1
```

This is going to simulate the pressing down (0) the releasing (1) of a button.

#### [Second method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034050/how-to-simulate-hardware-media-control-buttons-on-an-android-emulator)

This method uses `adb`, like so:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_BACK
```

### Ok so what?

After trying both, I realized that `telnet` didn't work but `adb` *did* work. I also checked the source code of `emulator` and saw that `telnet` relies on the same set of functions that are used by the tool-window. So it's probably a bug, and we can wait for the update to fix it, or...

### In the meantime

I downloaded the source code, wrote a janky workaround, and built it. Basically instead of using the keypress method, I use the `adb` method. If you want [here it is](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sEKngvJiWn7a3zncj716gSo_GXqA6X1m?usp=sharing). It's quite voluminous so be patient. I included a small script to automatically replace the emulator, just run:

```
$ chmod +x replace
# ./reaplace path-to-android-sdk
```

This adds a new flag `-use-adb-toolwindow` to `emulator`. When you activate it it will use adb (successfully) for *most* of keyboard inputs, and home, back, apps and power buttons. Like I said it's a quick fix, but for me it works fine.

##### Note:

I have no clue where the bug is, so I didn't do any report, hopefuly as more people get this issue it will become clearer.

Answer (score 10):

The best option would (Needs to be done for every emulator you install)

**Windows**

1. `%USERPROFILE%\.adnroid\avd\<Emulator Name>.avd`
2. Edit `config.ini`
3. Change `hw.keyboard=no` to `hw.keyboard=yes`

**Mac**

1. `~/.android/avd/<Emulator Name>.avd`
2. Edit `config.ini`
3. Change `hw.keyboard=no` to `hw.keyboard=yes`

---

The answer is based on [this](https://www.makarablue.com/2022/07/fix-android-emulator-back-button-home.html) article